# Import the .sql database files in android

Tags: android, sql, database, nosql

I have some many data files( .sql files ), each containing data in this format -

```
tbl_dim_1
5
0
CONTENT
'Data entry 1'
tbl_dim_1
6
0
CONTENT
'Data entry 2'
tbl_dim_1
7
0
CONTENT
'Data entry 3'
tbl_dim_1
8
0
CONTENT
'Data entry 4'
tbl_dim_1
9
0
CONTENT
'Data entry 5'
tbl_dim_1
10
0
CONTENT
'Data entry 6'
tbl_dim_1
11
0
```

and so on.
Is there any way to import these .sql files into my android app and populate data in the app. I've worked earlier with sqlite databases in android but i'm unable to find appropiate way to import this type of data because i can't recognise this format of these data files. Also is there is any API suitable for this task?

Comment: NoSQL is far too general a net. If you have a particular engine in mind then ask ( or better yet actually look for ) the specific question of the specific engine. Unlike "SQL", the general methods differ greatly ( and arguably differ greatly between SQL engines, unless you are specifically asking for "ANSI-SQL" approaches intended to be common ). You also seem to be under the question that "nosql" or "database" attracts a wider audience. It does not. If you mean something specific ( and you really do ) then it is far more useful to yourself and others to ask that question directly instead.

Comment: @NeilLunn What i meant in this question was that i had some .sql files containing data in this format, i don't know whether it is NoSQL or something else( i'm a beginner ). I need to import these .sql files into my android application and populate data in my app. Previously i've done this task( of using sql files in android ) with SQLiteDatabase api of android on some .sql files containing data in tables format but since this type of data doesn't has any tables i'm confused on how to do this task.